# Give an alias in a join statement without changing the select statement (*) in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I'm working with queries in espressionengine, and I'm coding them with the codeigniter syntax. Here's my query:

```
$sql = ee()->db->select('*');
$sql = ee()->db->from('sometable');
$sql = ee()->db->where('id', $hidden_id);
$sql = ee()->db->get();
```

I'd like to add a join in order to get another value like that:

```
 $sql = ee()->db->join('another_table', 'sometable.another_table_id, another_table.id);
```

Now the problem is that in the join statement I add another column with the same name (id).

Instead of changing the select statement (*) I'd like to add an alias in the join statement something like:

```
 $sql = ee()->db->join('another_table', 'sometable.another_table_id, another_table.id as another_table_id);
```

Is it doable?

Comment: no this gives u error like `You have an error in your SQL syntax` but you can use subquery instead

Comment: How can I do a subquery?

Comment: do something like this `SELECT * FROM sometable t1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM anothertable t2  WHERE t1.id = t2.another_id) AND
 id = 1;`

Comment: yeah, but this is the normal syntax, I'm looking for the codeingiter syntax

Comment: Something like: // Sub Query
$mysql = ee()->db->select('id as credit_id')->from('exp_credit_tracker_credit_type');
$subQuery = ee()->db->get_compiled_select($mysql);

// Main Query
$sql = ee()->db->select('*')
->from('exp_credit_tracker_assoc')
->join("($subQuery)", NULL, FALSE)
->get()
->result();

Comment: SELECT * FROM sometable stable JOIN (SELECT id AS credit_id FROM another_table) as a_table

Comment: Please, add it as an answer so I can mark it!

Comment: you can also get result from this query with the help of `$this->db->query();`

Comment: Are  primary key and foreign key in both table has the same column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*And your query should be like this :*

Use this if both primary and foreign key has same column name :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('sometable stable');
$this->db->join('(SELECT id  
FROM another_table ) as a_table' ,'id');
$query = $this->db->get();
print_r($query->result());
```

if not please use this :

Make sure in join here `a_table.id = stable.id` , `primary` and `foreign` key match here

```
$this->db->select('*,a_table.id as credit_id');
$this->db->from('sometable stable');
$this->db->join('another_table a_table','a_table.id = stable.id');
$query = $this->db->get();


print_r($query->result());
```

You can also get result from this query with the help of `$this->db->query();`

```
$sql = 'your query here';
$query = $this->db->query();
print_r($query->result());
```

Comment: My query is exactly like that one and it works, but I'm looking for the CodeIgniter version because I need to sanitize it and exclude the join part if I need to

Comment: hope this will for you pls check